# different size facets proportional of x axis on ggplot 2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

The following is a situation:

```
group1 <- seq(1, 10, 2)
group2 <-  seq(1, 20, 3)
x = c(group1, group2)
mydf <- data.frame (X =x , Y = rnorm (length (x),5,1), 
 groups = c(rep(1, length (group1)), rep(2, length(group2))))

ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y, group= groups)) + geom_point()+ facet_grid (.~ group)
```

Different facets are scaled by x limits in the following plot:

```
 ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y, group= groups)) + geom_point()+ 
   facet_grid (.~ group, scales = "free_x")
```

As total width of x has meaning, I want to produce facets of different width not only different scale. Thus the expected facet 1's wideth should be half the size of 2.

[image]

Comment: BTW, I couldn't get your example to run. I suggested editorial changes but they were rejected.   In the calls to `facet.grid()`, I used `. ~ groups` in place of `. ~ group`. Also, `group = groups` in the aesthetics statements is not needed.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,  `space = "free_x"` does what you want in `facet_grid`. As far as I know, `facet_wrap` has never supported a space argument, but many `facet_wrap` commands can be cast as `facet_grid` commands.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()+ 
facet_grid (.~ groups, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

And if you want the same style of labelling on the x axes:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(X, Y)) + geom_point()+ 
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20,2)) +
 facet_grid (.~ groups, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: `space` is only supported for `facet_grid`. What to do for `facet_wrap`? Any options?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment about `space`, because I discovered the unrecognized-argument error was specific to `facet_wrap`.

Comment: @PaulMcMurdie  As far as I know, `facet-wrap` has never supported a `space` argument, but many `facet_wrap` commands can be cast as `facet-grid` commands. If you have a plot where that is not feasible, it might be better to ask a new question.