# Different size facets at x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

Length of x-axis is important for my plot because it allows one to compare between facets, therefore I want facets to have different x-axis sizes. Here is my example data:

```
group1 <- seq(1, 10, 2)
group2 <-  seq(1, 20, 3)
x = c(group1, group2)
mydf <- data.frame (X =x , Y = rnorm (length (x),5,1), 
                    groups = c(rep(1, length (group1)), rep(2, length(group2))))
```

And my code:

```
p1 = ggplot(data=mydf,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=factor(groups)) )+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels=comma)+
  theme_bw()
p1+facet_grid(groups ~ .,scales = "fixed",space="free_x")
```

And the resulting figure:

[image]

Panel-1 has x-axis values less then 10 whereas panel-2 has x-axis value extending to 20. Still both panels and have same size on x-axis. Is there any way to make x-axis panel size different for different panels, so that they correspond to their (x-axis) values?

I found an example from some different package that shows what I am trying to do, here is the figure:
[image]

Comment: I think this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454805/different-size-facets-proportional-of-x-axis-on-ggplot-2-r?rq=1 may answer your question.

Comment: If you want to compare between facets, isn't having the same axis better?  In the example plot, it looks like all facets have the same x-axis scale.  If you drew boxes around your data, it would look like the example figure.

Comment: Why not use mentioned package (ggbio)?

Comment: @mshum: Tried that but couldn't make it to work

Comment: @oshun I guess axis will be same but the boxes will be of variable size. Is it possible by plotting them separately and aligning in grid?

Comment: @zx8754 If I can just change facet size according to x-axis, then I can plot a lot of different stuff which is not possible through "ggbio".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this can get you started.  There's still some formatting to do, though.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(data=mydf[mydf$groups==1,],aes(x=X,y=Y))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  theme_bw()
p2 <- ggplot(data=mydf[mydf$groups==2,],aes(x=X,y=Y))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  theme_bw()

summ <- mydf %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize(len=diff(range(X)))
summ$p <- summ$len/max(summ$len)
summ$q <- 1-summ$p

ng <- nullGrob()
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,ng,widths=summ[1,3:4]),
             arrangeGrob(p2,ng,widths=summ[2,3:4]))
```

[image]

I'm sure there's a way to make this more general, and the axes don't line up perfectly yet, but it's a beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution following OP's clarifying comment ("I guess axis will be same but the boxes will be of variable size. Is it possible by plotting them separately and aligning in grid?").

```
library(plyr); library(ggplot2)

buffer <- 0.5 # Extra space around the box

#Calculate box parameters
mydf.box <- ddply(mydf, .(groups), summarise,
      max.X = max(X) + buffer,
      min.X = 0,
      max.Y = max(Y) + buffer,
      min.Y = 0,
      X = mean(X), Y = mean(Y)) #Dummy values for X and Y needed for geom_rect


p2 <- ggplot(data=mydf,aes(x=X, y=Y) )+ 
  geom_rect(data = mydf.box, aes( xmax = max.X, xmin = min.X, 
                                  ymax = max.Y, ymin = min.Y),
            fill = "white", colour = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_point(size=2) +  facet_grid(groups ~ .,scales = "free_y") +
  theme_classic() +
  #Extra formatting to make your plot like the example
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey85"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = "grey65"))
```

[image: p2]

Comment: Thanks for cleanest solution. I found that sam's solution below gives me more control though it's different from what I asked.

Comment: For your question, the answer I gave should be enough to simulate the example graph. But yes, grobs are the best for fine-tune control, and @Sam's answer is a good one!

Comment: Can you help me with a related question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111220/add-geom-segment-to-geom-point-plot-in-ggplot