# ggplot facet_wrap consistently spaced categorical x axis across all facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

When using `scales="free_x"` in `facet_wrap` the default seems to be that every subplot will take up the same amount of horizontal space and the x axes in each subplot will be scaled in order for this to happen. Is it possible to have the scale of the x axes be constant across the facets (with the width of each subplot different if necessary)?

For example, running the following code produces a plot where the variables on the x axis on the right are further apart than on the left (since there are 2 and 3 different values of x respectively). Is there a way to make it so the space between a,b,c and d,e is the same?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 y=1:5,
                 type=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2))


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(.~type, scales = "free_x")
print(p)
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454805/different-size-facets-proportional-of-x-axis-on-ggplot-2-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `facet_grid()` with the argument `space = "free"`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(.~type, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

Output is:

[image]